# My MikTex keep create corrupted .tex file

Tags: miktex

[image]

When I use MikTex + TexStudio, after sometime when I compile & build, it will came up this error message, then the file become corrupted and size is 0kb. I am not sure what happened.

My compiler is pdflatex, but when I change the compiler so that DVI->PS->Pdf it also happen

Comment: well, my first guess would be to check if you are really running that low on space on your hard drive – then consider that your hard drive might be nearing the end of it's (≈8-year) life. Does it happen when you compile from the command line?

Comment: I put my tex file on a SD card, and it works well besides Latex

Comment: I suspect that the SD card has become damaged.   Try compiling to another device/media item.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems the SD card cause the problem